# react-native-share-menu share extension view that does ShareMenuReactView.continueInApp causes origin app to freeze

Tags: ios, react-native

I've implemented the [react-native-share-menu](https://github.com/Expensify/react-native-share-menu/tree/master) library in my React Native app, and have also implemented its recommended [SHARE_EXTENSION_VIEW](https://github.com/Expensify/react-native-share-menu/blob/master/SHARE_EXTENSION_VIEW.md) code, which will cause any share intent to directly open my app, as per [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66804996/19276472). Notably, this is done via `ShareMenuReactView.continueInApp({shareInfo: data});`

This flow works great:

- From another app on the phone, click the Share button
- The iOS Share drawer opens up
- I select my RN app from the choices
- It opens up my app (the whole app, not just a view), with the link / photo / etc. that I want to share in my app. My app can work just fine from there

But, when I return to the origin app, it's frozen - I have to force stop it and restart it. I've done a bit of testing, and it seems that both the NY Times and Wikipedia apps freeze, but interestingly Yelp does not. I don't have another app on my phone that has the behavior of completely opening the destination app, so hard to tell if NY Times and Wikipedia would also freeze with those.

Has anybody else seen this issue? Any suggestions on how to debug?